# Indent with conditions

Tags: vim, indentation

I would like to indent every line with 5 spaces when all the next conditions are matched:

1) after an empty line
2) when line starts with a Uppercase letter
3) when the line has more then 80 characters when the file has no textwidth set
4) when the line has more then (textwidth-10) characters when the file has a textwidth set
   and the next line must not start with a Uppercase letter.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you want to modify the auto-indent behaviour so that the indentation happens while you type (in which case I can't really help), or as a "beautify" function to be called on an existing file (in which case I have done something very similar in the past)?

Comment: I don't want to modify the auto-indent behavior. I want to use it as a beautify function for an existing file. I tried to create a vimscript but I haven't an idea how to check only the lines starting with capital letter for their line length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is completely untested, and I'm sure there are more elegant methods, but this should give you a rough idea. I scan every line in the file one at a time, and indent it if one of your conditions is met.

```
function! Indenter()
    let winview=winsaveview()
    try
        let this_line_num=1
        let tw = &textwidth
        while this_line_num <= line("$")
            let thisline=getline(this_line_num)
            let lastline=getline(this_line_num-1)
            let firstchar=substitute(matchstr(thisline,"^ *.")," ","","g")
            if ( matchstr(lastline,"^.") == "" && this_line_num > 1 )
                        \ || firstchar =~# "[A-Z]"
                        \ || ( tw == 0 && strlen(thisline) > 80 )
                        \ || ( tw != 0 && strlen(thisline) > tw-10
                                     \ && firstchar !~# "[A-Z]" )
                sil exe this_line_num . "s#^#     #"
            endif
            let this_line_num+=1
        endwhile
    finally
        call winrestview(winview)
    endtry
endfunction
```

I am assuming that "empty lines" means no whitespace (hence `matchstr(lastline,"^.")`) and that lines containing text can have leading whitespace (hence the `substitute(matchstr())` command to get the first non-whitespace character.

Hope this helps. Let me know if it falls flat on its face.

Comment: @Prince Goulash, thank you very much! I found a little spell error (substitue --> substitute) but after this it intended text but... 1) it intend text only when my mouse is on the line. I would like to check the whole file and intend only the lines which matches the above conditions 2) it intends sometimes 45 spaces, sometimes 50 spaces, not 5 spaces.

Comment: My key mistake was not specifying the linenumber for the :s operation, so it always operated on the current line. I have corrected this and changed the "no textwidth" definition to 0. This should work slightly better now, but I only tested it on some simple cases.

Comment: thank you, it works fine. Can I ask you just two more things? 1) What do I have to change to let the empty lines also contain spaces? 2) what do I have to change to avoid the leading whitespace in a sentence? (this to avoid that if I change a letter at the start of a sentence from lowercase to uppercase and use the function again all other sentences intend again with 5 spaces)

Comment: To ignore lines with leading whitespace, change the declaration of firstchar to `let firstchar=matchstr(thisline,"^.")` (so the first character is always considered, even if it is a space).

Comment: To allow "empty" lines to contain spaces, change the first conditional of the if-statement to `( matchstr(lastline,"^ *$") == lastline && ... )`. There must be a more elegant way that this, but this is the way I always do it.